# ROBLOX - why isn't a boolValue being created in the player's Character?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I write:

```
local BoolValue = Instance.new("BoolValue")
BoolValue.Parent = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Character
```

In a starter player script (local Script)

But it's not doing anything seemingly, I can't find a BoolValue in the player's character

Answer (score 0):

Even if the script is a localscript or serverscript, your code won't work.
Alternatively, you can add a BoolValue in StarterCharacterScripts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be a script, **not** a local script.

A local script runs on client side, meaning that it only affects the client.

Just change this to a script (which runs on server side) in `ServerScriptService`.
Which will need a couple of adjustments
Here's the code:

```lua
--this runs when a player connects to the server
game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    --create the BoolValue
    local BoolValue = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    --this runs when the player's character is created
    --this is used so that the BoolValue parent is the character and not null
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character: Model)
        --Move the BoolValue to the character!
        BoolValue.Parent = character
    end)
end)
```

Basically, client side (local scripts) only run on the client (only the player)

And server side (scripts) run for everyone on the server

And another way to do this is by creating an instance of BoolValue and moving it into `StarterCharacterScripts` *(which also works)*